# find all p, for which the determinant is divisible by $p^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, determinant

So, we have to find all prime numbers $p$ such that

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to somehow count the determinant itself using eliminations; Like for each row subtracting the previous row. Then I got an expression for the determinant which was divisible by $p^{2}$  but could not go any further.

Comment: Could you add that to your question?  I'm sure your expression for the determinant could be helpful.  In general, question posts on this site are supposed to include some context from the asker in addition to the question statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** One approach for getting an expression for the determinant is to use the [matrix-determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) with
$$
A = \pmatrix{2^2 - 1\\ & 3^2-1 \\ && \ddots \\&&& (p+7)^2 - 1}, \quad u = v = (1,1,\dots,1)^T.
$$
Doing so yields the expression
$$
\det(M) =  \left(1 + \sum_{i=2}^{p+7} \frac{1}{i^2 - 1} \right)\cdot \prod_{i=2}^{p+7} (i^2 - 1)\\
= \left(1 + \frac 12 \sum_{i=2}^{p+7} \left[\frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i+1}\right] \right)\cdot \prod_{i=2}^{p+7} (i^2 - 1).
$$
Note that the sum is telescoping.

Comment: seems interesting, I am gonna try that lemma and let's see what happens then. Thanks!